# Call a spinner's onClickListener with another button or control

Tags: android, android-widget, android-spinner

Is it possible to call a `Spinner`'s `onClickListener` (the one that makes the `Spinner`'s list of items come up) from another `Button`?  If so, how do I do this? I'm thinking along the lines of iOS, where if I wanted to call a control's action from elsewhere I could reference the control and send the appropriate callback message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
spinner.performClick();
```

you can display spinner using onclick of button.So put above line in your button's clicklistener.